# Change the style and add pictures

Tags: beamer

I need to make a presentation and am using `beamer`. I need to change this style. I want to replace this way:

Standard style (wide or German, I need only one style) looks this way:

[image: standard style]

And what I need is to add two fields in the upper part of the slide and in the lower part of the slide, but it can be my own style (this pictures must be on every slide)

[image: needed style]

How can I do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I uploaded the images for you. Tip: as new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: It would be helpful to have some more information here, e.g. what `beamer` theme you are currently using, what the height of these additional fields should be, ...

Comment: \usetheme{Ilmenau}

Comment: the size of the pictures: 130 px is height of the upper picture and 50 px height of the lower picture. I can resize the upper picture, but the proportion must be the same

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is still very unclear to me: So the whole bars marked in your picture, including the blue background, are external images? Regarding the size specifications: Pixel is a device-dependent measure, while LaTeX/PDF uses "absolute" units like `pt` or `cm`. The frame size of a `beamer` presentation is 128 x 96 mm, by the way.